# Add a multiple lines of text column to a list allowing unlimited lines of text, html enabled using powershell

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

Below is my code,

```
param([string]$workspaceUrl)
[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity]::RunWithElevatedPrivileges(
{
    $site = SPSite($workspaceUrl)
    $web = $site.RootWeb
    $spList = $web.Lists["ListName"]
    $spFieldType = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::Note
    $spList.Fields.Add("YourColumn",$spFieldType,$false)
    $spList.Update()
})
```

How can I set the field to multiple lines of text, allowing rich text and unlimited lines of text with powershell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your script like so, and you're good to go:

```
param([string]$workspaceUrl)
[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity]::RunWithElevatedPrivileges(
{
    $site = SPSite($workspaceUrl)
    $web = $site.RootWeb
    $spList = $web.Lists["ListName"]
    $spFieldType = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::Note
    $newFieldName = $spList.Fields.Add("YourColumn", $spFieldType, $false)
    $newField = $spList.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName($newFieldName)
    if ($spList.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary") {
        $newField.UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary = $true
    }
    $newField.RichText = $true
    $newField.RichTextMode = "FullHtml" #enables the Ribbon editor
    $newField.Update()
    $spList.Update()
})
```

Comment: Thanks Mark :) 
and for removing the number of lines limit?

Comment: I updated my answer. You only need to set the unlimited length in case your list is a document library. If it's just a plain list, the Note field is already unlimited.

Comment: thanks upvoted and accepted answer
I saw the number of lines - 6 in the column, wanted to increase that to accommodate more lines

Comment: "Number of lines" is only used to define the height of the edit box. It doesn't say anything about the number of lines you can put in there. If you like, you can change this as well through PowerShell: $newField.NumberOfLines = 10

Comment: if possible, please share a link where I can learn these